# docker-compose volumes not updating until re run

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file with some set volumes. When I make a change in any file in the folder referred tp the volume, I have to rerun docker-compose up to make it have an effect, rather than updating when saving the file. I am using Windows 11 with the WSL support.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  detection-api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app
```

When I perform any change in any file on the app directory inside my working dir (Windows) it does not update the file inside the container.

Answer (score -1):

Use this command:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

It force Docker to rebuild the image using the latest files.